# Close div when click on another button

Tags: jquery, html

I have two elements with the same name that contains some hidden `content`. When I click on the `button` the `content` is shown.

Till here everything is perfect, now I am wondering how can I `hide` the `content` in the other `div` when I click on one of the two divs?

e.g. If I click on the `first button(A)` and the content show up, I want the content from the first `div` to disappear I `click` on the `second button(B)`. I want to keep the same class name though and not adding extra markup or different `class/ID` names!!

```
var openAccordionContent = function() {
        var $buttons = $('.accordion-content-button'),
            $content = $('.accordion-content');


        $buttons.each(function() {
            var $button = $(this),
            $content = $button.next('.accordion-content');

            $button.on("click", function(){
                $content.toggleClass('show');
                return false;
            });  

        });
    }();
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vx2bguyp/3/):

Comment: You're clearly _overdoing_ things here.

Comment: yes I know I was over complicated thing, I was trying to follow best practices as that code is a snippet of a big script :(

Answer (score 1):

It could be as simple as that:

```
var openAccordionContent = function () {
    $('.accordion-content-button').on('click', function () {
        var $next_content = $(this).next('.accordion-content');

        // Remove the class show from all the items, except the one
        // sitting next to the clicked one.
        $('.accordion-content').not($next_content).removeClass('show');

        // Toggle the class show for the item which is sitting next
        // to the clicked one.
        $next_content.toggleClass('show');
    });
}();
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/vx2bguyp/12/)

Comment: hey this works but when I click on the button it doesnt close anymore (I have to click on the other button) hope this makes sense

Comment: It should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `removeClass` (on all but the selected one) and `toggleClass` instead on the selected one:

You can also simplify that code *a lot*:

```
$('.accordion-content-button').click(function(){
    var $accord = $(this).next('.accordion-content');
    $('.accordion-content').not($accord).removeClass('show');
    $accord.toggleClass('show');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vx2bguyp/16/

Comment: same as above, if I click on the same button the content does not hide anymore...

Comment: @greatTeacherOnizuka: Quite right. Updated to use exclusion and `toggleClass` instead.